# How do i use the progressbar to indicate progress without having any steps in the process in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, progress-bar

How do I indicate progress using the progressbar for a process with no steps. The process simply sends an sql query to a oracle server, which then will process the query for some time. In this time I have no means (steps) of setting progress correctly, so I would rather just let the progress bar show progress like it is the case in Windows and many windows programs (no actual progress, the progress indicating simply moves to the end and starts over until the process is done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the style of the progress bar to:

```
ProgressBarStyle.Marquee
```

Example:

[image]
[image]